# Textbox in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have `Gridview` like this.

[image]

Here is my last column `Gridview` code;

```
<EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTNOT" runat="server" Height="35" TextMode="MultiLine" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource8" runat="server" 
              ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlServerCstr %>" 
              SelectCommand="SELECT [T_NOT] FROM [TAKIP] WHERE T_HESAP_NO = @T_HESAP_NO ">
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="T_HESAP_NO" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
```

My last column has a Textbox.

When i import to excel with this code;

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TahTakip.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";


    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
  }
```

Still i have a `Textbox` in my `Excel` file.

[image]

How can i delete `Textbox` [NOT VALUE INSIDE COLUMN] when i exporting to `Excel`?

**Best Regards,**

**Soner**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach as shown in this link(http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html).  I would suggest to replace textbox with Label controls to avoid this.

Comment: How can i replace textbox with label when i export it?

Comment: @Soner I would suggest to replace textbox before export step when gridview is in display mode.

Comment: We have to use Textbox in Gridview. We enter a data and then we save it. But i don't want Textbox in Excel. Just a normal cell with value.